# Github Actions: Create a pull request to the base repo when a pr occurs to the forked repo

Tags: github, pull-request, github-actions

I am struggling with redirecting a PR, which was made to the forked repo, to the base repo.

Let say,

I have a base repo named `Base` which is private and includes some unit tests.
Then I create a forked repo from `Base` named `Forked` which is public.
After that, I made a new commit to the `Base` repo that adds some private unit tests.

If a person opens a PR to the `Forked` repo, I can inform the `Base` repo with the help of the `repository_dispatch` event. For information about these processes, please look at [here.](https://blog.marcnuri.com/triggering-github-actions-across-different-repositories/)

But, I can't create an automated PR to the `Base` repo to make private unit tests run.

I want to run private unit tests against the PR which is made to `Forked` repo and I don't want to expose the private unit tests.

I am stuck here, have made so much research but can't get even close.
And I am using JavaCI.

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth taking another look at how you have your code organized. I'd recommend completely separating your **private tests** from your **public code**. This will simplify some things, and help avoid merge conflicts in the future.

I have a couple solutions in mind, but they may require you to build your own action from scratch. (I haven't dealt with the dispatch event before, so you may need to tweak my explanations a bit to work with it.) Hopefully it can get you pointed in the right direction though!

With your code being public, you could setup an action on your private repository to [clone the public code from the pull request](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/checking-out-pull-requests-locally), set up the test environment, and run the private tests. However, this would keep your tests and test status private, so it may not be all that useful.

Alternatively, you could use [secrets](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/creating-and-using-encrypted-secrets) to store credentials for your private repository and set up an action to clone your private tests, set up the test environment, and run the private (and public?) tests. While this would make the test *status* public, it has the potential to keep the tests private. However, you'll need to take care to avoid leaking the *output* of the tests (eg, test names, exceptions, and other output) otherwise some data may become public. Setting up one action for public tests and another for private may make more sense depending on how your tests are set up, as you could redirect *all* output to `/dev/null` or equivalent.